# How to publish website using Vis Studio Web Developer Express Edition

Tags: visual-web-developer

In the MSDN Documentation is says:

"Note: 
The Publish Web Site utility is not available in Visual Web Developer Express edition."

That being said, does that mean that I can not upload my website to my server to be viewable online unless I purchase the full version of Web Developer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you build, copy over your physical compiled website directory to the server directory where IIS is pointing.

Comment: Thank you George. I tried that at first but it didn't work. But I just tried it again now it's working. I obviously copied over the wrong files to being with Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read through [Web Site Deployment in Visual Web Developer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5c12ykae(VS.80).aspx) on MSDN to learn how to deploy a website with Visual Web Developer.

Good luck, and hope this helps some.